# What causes a Date to be <null> while specifically selecting the NOT NULL fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

In one of my MYSQL databases, I have done the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date_column < 1971-01-01 AND date_column IS NOT NULL;
```

This returns about 3000 items where the date is shown as NULL in the mysql command line prompt, and in the IntelliJ IDEA mysql database editor.

The column has a DATE type.

The database is a copy of a prod database environment that has been running for a couple years.

How can a record end up in that state ? What is that state ? How can I fix it properly ?

PS: The `< 1971/01/01` clause was just to filter the correct dates out of the query. If I just query on the IS NOT NULL clause, I still get these weird dates of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised this works.  First, date constants should be surrounded by single quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE date_column < '1971-01-01' AND date_column IS NOT NULL;
```

Second, this cannot return a `NULL` value for date_column.  This suggests one of two things:

- `date_col` is actually another type, such as `varchar` and you are seeing `'NULL'` the string, not `NULL` the value.
- another column is `NULL`.

Comment: Alright, my query gave some weird results in MySQL command line, with your query, I get dates which have 0000-00-00 as their values. I guess that explains what their state is, and how to fix it. I have no clue how it could end up in that state though.

Comment: @Saffron . . . That is often a default value for a date if it doesn't accept `NULL` values.